# Image getting corrupted while sending via http

Tags: image, vue.js, go

I'm trying to build an application with VueJS frontend and Golang backend. Part of it sending images uploaded by user to backend for storing. This is how I do it on frontend:

```
uploadPic(event, prodInd, imgInd) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
      this.products[prodInd].images[imgInd] = byteArray.join(", ")
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
}
...
<input @change="event => uploadPic(event, prodInd, imgInd)" type="file" placeholder="Загрузите фотографию">
```

Then, on backend, I try to parse this byte array into an actual photo to save it:

```
func (p *Product) GetImages(l *log.Logger) []image.Image {
    res := make([]image.Image, len(p.Media))
    for i, img := range p.Media {
        l.Debug(img)
        // split to get separate bytes of image
        strArr := strings.Split(img, ", ")
        var byteArr []byte
        for _, c := range strArr {
            // we now that bytes are in these strings, so it should be fine
            cur, _ := strconv.ParseUint(c, 10, 8)
            byteArr = append(byteArr, uint8(cur))
        }
        // parse image
        curimg, form, err := image.Decode(bytes.NewReader(byteArr))
        l.Debug(form)
        if err != nil || (form != "png" && form != "jpg" && form != "jpeg") {
            if err != nil {
                l.Debug("decoder err: " + err.Error())
            }
            continue
        }
        res[i] = curimg
    }
    return res
}
```

I get error "unknow format" from image.Decode. I don't really know where to look for the problem, is it wrong encoding on client side or am I missing something on server side? The only thing I can tell is that when I try to send a png, first bytes of resulting sequence are compliant with png format (but I haven't checked the rest).

Edit: I have tried using base64, as comment suggests.
I do it like

```
source := <base64 encoded image here>
src := strings.Split(source, ",")[1] // I need this because source looks like data:image/png;base64, + actual data
dst := make([]byte, len(src))
_, err := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(dst, []byte(src))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
_, form, err := image.Decode(bytes.NewReader(dst))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(form)
```

And I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try using base64 encoding the image instead of a comma-separated string.

Comment: @BurakSerdar doesn't seem to help

Comment: The point of base64 is to not use commas and splitting.

Comment: You don’t have a [mre], have you imported the necessary decoders? Why are you decoding it in the first place? An image is already encoded in a format suitable for saving, decoding it gives you the raw pixel data.